# Load data local infile ignorar lineas especificas

Tags: mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Buenas tengo la siguiente cuestion necesito cargar un csv en mi base de datos para ello actualmente estoy usando load data infile una consulta q me resulta muy util por su velocidad pero necesito poder ignorar algunas lineas q van a venir vacias en el csv. Quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de poder saltarme esas filas por una posicion o algo.

Este es mi codigo:

load data local infile 'D:\Objetivos.csv' into table OBJETIVOS_PREGUNTAS_PUNTOS_DE_RELEVAMIENTOS fields
TERMINATED by ';' LINES TERMINATED by '\r\n'
ignore 1 lines (@column1, @column2, @column3, @column4, @column5, @column6, @column7, @column8, @column9) SET pais = @column1, codigo_distribuidor = @column2, codigo_punto = @column3, codigo_encuesta =@column5, codigo_pregunta = @column7, id_canal_arcor = (SELECT id_canal_arcor FROM puntos_de_relevamiento WHERE codigo_punto = @column3 UNION (SELECT '-1') LIMIT 1), objetivo=(IF(LENGTH(@column9)>0,@column9,0) )

PD: El csv no se puede cambiar, siempre va a tener la misma estructura.Ej:
14,ddd,Cuba,MN

16,TYG,España,EUR

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: [mre]

Comment: Para poder contestar adecuadamente esta pregunta se necesita una muestra representativa de los datos y el código base para partir. Sin eso, quien quiera responder tendrá que partir de cero. Eso no es muy alentador.